# Get Attribute With Underscore From Product Object?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

The name of my attribute is Current Standards (default label)
The code of my attribute is `current_standards`
The type of my attribute is multiple select

However the following code run on a product object (`$product`) doesn't return any data that is clearly set, nor does it throw an error.

In Block:

```
class Display extends Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable 
{

/* This class contains not construct method. */

public function getOptionsArray()
{
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    return $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
}
```

In `Template/Summary`:

```
foreach ($block->getOptionsArray() as $option) {
    $option->getData('current_standards')
    $option->getCurrentStandards()
}
```

Both fail to return any data.

Comment: if you print out `$product->getData()` do you see a key `current_standards` in the array ?

Comment: No, I don't believe it is.

Comment: Then it means the value of the field is not loaded. Maybe you should add the context in which you are calling these methods.

Comment: Any ideas? is it due to the scope or the type of the attribute?

var_dump(array_keys($product->getAttributes())) has the attribute key.

Comment: Marius, my class extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable  without having a constructor - is that the problem?

Comment: it should not be a problem. But please add to the question mode code.

Comment: Done. Added more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `getUsedProducts` method does not load all the product attributes.
So, most probably your attribute is not loaded either.
You need to edit your attribute and set `Used in product listing` to `Yes` then rebuild your indexes.
Then it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a good answer and I'll try it soon. I thought that getUsedProducts returned the standard product models.

Comment: This was an incredible answer, thanks again.